# Nested foreach loops c#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

```
        foreach (int i in a.set)
        {
            foreach (int k in b.set)
            {
                if (i < k)
                {
                    return true;                                
                }
                else if (i > k)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }


        return false;
    }
```

I got two sets, a set includes 3,4,6
 b.set includes 3,4,5

The problem is that the outer loop only iterates once. But it contains 3 elements, why is that?

Comment: return call does not break the loop but get out of the method.

Comment: unless i == k the inner loop doesn't iterate either

Comment: Do u really have a doubt..? return false breaks the iteration of the loop.. to achieve the same functionality use break.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Right now the method exits in the second iteration of the inner loop, as `a.set[0] < b.set[1]`, i.e. `3 < 4`, thus returning `true`.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the values inside a and b, if one value inside the a.set is lower than one value inside the b.set the b.set is bigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You return in your inner loop. This immediately exits the containing method.

- `i` is `3` (the first element of `a.set` – let's assume that order for now).

  - `k` is `3` (same as above)
  - `k` is `4` – therefore the `if` condition in the inner loop is met and the method returns with `true`.

As you can see, you don't get the chance of iterating through all values of `a.set` before returning from the method.

Answer (score 3):

Use "break" insted of "return", it interrupts only one level

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are exiting your `foreach-loop` by returning a value on the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code and data you provided, the inner loop will exit the function with a return of true on the second iteration.  There is no way in your code for the outer foreach to iterate more than once.

If you want to write code that returns true, if at any point set `a` has a number less than set `b`, you should do this:

```
foreach (int i in a.set)
{
    foreach (int k in b.set)
    {
        if (i < k)
        {
            return true;                                
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use break instead of return - when you return (which will happen on the second iteration of the inner loop when 3 > 4), it will stop the execution of the loop and return from the function/method you have this in